# Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration in SSIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, ssis, azure-devops

I am running a Microsoft Azure enabled project on Visual Studio 2019. I created a script task to erase all of the files in a blob container using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, however, it gives me the following error:

Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried downgrading the version to SQL 2012 but it says it needs to be SQL 2017 in order to have Azure enabled.

The code is the following:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure;

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient;

//connection is kept in app.config
storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(conectionString));
cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

Parallel.ForEach(cloudBlobClient.ListContainers(), x =>
{
    Parallel.ForEach(x.ListBlobs(), y =>
         {
            ((CloudBlockBlob)y).DeleteIfExists();
          });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration dll is referenced in your solution.

The simplest way is to just use NuGet Package Manager and install Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.

Without this your project may work locally but it will fail on Azure.